Go Mod Download in a SSH only nested private repository in a docker container
I am currently trying to build a go application in a docker container.
This go application uses some private golang modules, that are hosted in subgroups of private repositories. The nesting can be 3 to 4 groups deep.
These groups have only SSH enabled, and cant be cloned with HTTPS.
I am using gitlab for the hosting of my private repositories
So far ive tried a lot of things, ranged from adding a ssh key, to creating a .netrc file in the container, none of which have really worked.
Right now I am using buildkit to use SSH mode on the docker build command, and running --mount=type=ssh.
The weird thing is that I can perfectly clone the repository in the docker container. However, the go mod download does not work.
Currently what I have which works for cloning is
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental

#Specify the go version image
FROM golang:1.23.2 AS build-stage

# setup Git & SSH (for getting dependencies)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git openssh-client

RUN git config --global url."git@gitlab.com:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/"
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'

ENV GOPRIVATE=gitlab.com/myorg/*

WORKDIR /

COPY dummy/go.mod dummy/go.sum ./

RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@gitlab.com:myorg/group/repo.git /tmp/test-repo

RUN --mount=type=ssh GOLOG=debug go mod download -x


... rest omitted 

This will work for the git clone, but not for the go mod download.
My build command is
docker build --ssh default  -t  tag:test -f Dockerfile.multistage .


